# sufficient condition for $\mathbb{E}_P[X]$ to lie within the convex hull of $\mathbb{E}_Q[X]$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, inequality

More precisely, I am curious if the following conditional is true:

Fix a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Let $\Delta(\Omega)$ denote the set of probability measures on $\Omega$ (we can assume that they are not necessarily countably additive for now, and I am curious if countable additivity matters for my question). Let $P\in\Delta(\Omega)$ and $\{Q_i\}_{i\in I}\subset\Delta, (\Omega)$. Suppose $\min_iQ_i(A)\leq P(A)\leq\max_iQ_i(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$. Does it follow that, for any bounded real-valued random variable $X$, $$\min_i\mathbb{E}_{Q_i}[X]\leq\mathbb{E}_{P}[X]\leq\max_i\mathbb{E}_{Q_i}[X]?$$ (If the measures are finitely additive, then the integrals are defined as the limit of the integral of simple functions that converge to $X$ uniformly, if it exists). I feel it does not, but I am having a hard time finding a precise counterexample. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Sigma = \{0, 1, 2\}$, and let $F$ be the power set.

Let $P$ be 1 w.p. $1/4$ and 2 w.p. $3/4$, $Q_1$ be the measure that puts $3/4$ on 2 and $1/4$ on 0. $Q_2$ be the measure that puts $1/2$ on 1 and $1/2$ on 2.

Your requirements are satisfied for all sets in $F$.

Let $X$ be the identity, and just take the expectations. The expectation of $X$ is highest under $P$.

Comment: Something of a converse to add: A condition that would make that inequality you wrote true would be that if P belonged in the convex hull of the Q_i s. Then, a linear functional would be maximized in the extremal points.

Comment: Lovely! Thanks so much! Yes I was thinking that because my condition is weaker than the condition that P belongs in the convex hull of Q_i's, the conditional should not be true.

Comment: No problem! Hope you checked the conditions for all 6 (non-trivial) sets in F by the way; I checked them and am pretty sure, but you should double check (my first answer was wrong).